# Convert string date format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS to timestamp presto

Tags: sql, datetime, presto

I have a string that looks like:

```
2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000
```

I am trying to convert this to a timestamp as follows:

```
select "date_parse"("date_format"('2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000', '%Y-%m-%dT%h:%iZ'), '%Y-%m-%dT%h:%iZ')
```

but i keep getting an error:

```
Unexpected parameters (varchar(26), varchar(15)) for function date_format. Expected: date_format(timestamp with time zone, varchar(x)) , date_format(timestamp, varchar(x))
```

Comment: `select date_parse('2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f')`

Comment: thanks. That worked but i just needed to tweak to `select date_parse('2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')`

Comment: Ah! Little typo.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in your example matches the format of timestamp literals in SQL, so you can convert it to a `timestamp` type by just casting the value to the desired type:

```
> select cast('2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000' as timestamp(6));
           _col0
----------------------------
 2022-03-30 17:18:09.569000
(1 row)
```